# Passing array to function of specific type

Tags: c#

I need help with this code. I cant make it work so.. something is unclear for me yet.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Solution
{
    static int[] foo(int[] array)
    {
        int[] xx = new int[array.Length];

        for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] *= 2;
            Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
        }

        return array;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] array = new int[4] {73, 67, 38, 33 };

        foo(array);

    }
}
```

How to rebuild *foo* function to return values from *array* ?

I saw a lot of help links with void function.. and they werent useful. When it comes to specific type of function I cant make it work.

Thanks

ddr8

Comment: If you want the value returned from `foo()` you just have to assign it to a variable: `int[] fooResult = foo(array);`

Comment: There are several things that `foo` is doing that are questionable, but it *is* returning `array`, and with it the values in it, already, isn't it? Can you explain a bit more what you're asking for?

Comment: If you do that `//Console.WriteLine(array[i]);` nothing will be printed out. Even if I add a variable you just showed it still returns no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class Solution
    {
        static int[] foo(int[] array)
        {
            int[] xx = new int[array.Length]; // Building this but not using it

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] *= 2; //Altering the input array changes the array in the Main method..

                Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
            }

            return array;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            int[] array = new int[4] { 73, 67, 38, 33 };

            foo(array); // Not assigning the values to an object.
            //After this step look at array it will be 146, 134, 76 , 66
        }
    }
```

So you are altering the original array in the foo method. you're passing the array object then overwriting the values.

You declare a new int[] xx but then do nothing to it, I think instead you should be copying the source array to the new xx int[].
Doing this doesn't alter the orignal int in the main method.
You can then assign the return value of the new array in the main method.
Example below:

```
    class Solution
    {
        static int[] foo(int[] array)
        {

        int[] xx = new int[array.Length];
        //Copy the array into the new array
        Array.Copy(array, xx, array.Length);  

            for (int i = 0; i < xx.Length; i++)
            {
                xx[i] *= 2; 

                Console.WriteLine(xx[i]);
            }
            return xx;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = new int[4] { 73, 67, 38, 33 };
            //Assign the new array to an object
            int[] newArray = foo(array);
        }
    }
```

Edit: 
I also saw you included linq at the top, if you were interested in using linq this would achieve the same result:

```
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                        int[] array = new int[4] { 73, 67, 38, 33 };
                        int[] newarr = array.Select(arrayvalue => arrayvalue * 2).ToArray();
            }
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code works.. and I need to practice using functions I think about this a totaly wrong way.

Comment: No worries, it's not a simple concept but once it clicks it clicks.  
        https://www.dotnetperls.com/static
         Check out these links https://www.dotnetperls.com/return 
        I love dotnetpearls they have great examples

Comment: Thank you for help and advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code does return an array, but you are:

1. Updating the value in `array` and not the new `xx` array
2. Not assigning the return value in `Main`

Here is where you are modifying the existing array and not the new array:

```
static int[] foo(int[] array)
{
    int[] xx = new int[array.Length];

    for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        // NOTE: modifying array, not xx
        array[i] *= 2;
        Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
    }

    // NOTE: returning array, not xx -- xx is not used
    return array;
}
```

Here is the missing assignment for the returned array:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = new int[4] {73, 67, 38, 33 };
    // You are not assigning the returned array here
    int[] newArray = foo(array);
}
```

Your other option is to pass the array as a `ref` parameter, if you need to change the array size:

```
static int[] foo(ref int[] array)
{
    // Modify array as necessary
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful awnser!